# Subir multiples imagenes ASP.NET Framework MVC5 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, input-file

Actualmente, estoy desarrollando un proyecto a gran escala para un emprendimiento en mi ciudad y necesito su ayuda del cómo puedo subir por medio de un input tipo file multiplex imágenes. En estos momentos el código me funciona para una sola imagen, pero necesito guardar múltiples imágenes seleccionadas por medio de ese input y de ser posible también tener la opción de poder limitar qué máximo se puedan subir o cargar 6 imágenes por registro, en este caso.

Inicialmente envio los datos por Ajax y los envio asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi Controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria mi Modelo o Capa Negocio

```
    public bool Guardar_Foto_Manager(EntManager_Usuario Obj, out string Mensaje)
    {
        return ObjDatos.Guardar_Foto_Manager(Obj, out Mensaje);
    }
```

Y este seria mi Capa de Datos

```
    public bool Guardar_Foto_Manager(EntManager_Usuario Obj, out string Mensaje)
    {
        bool resultado = false;
        Mensaje = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection ObjConexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion_SQL.Con_SQL))
            {
                string query = "update Manager.Usuario set Ruta = @Ruta, Foto = @Foto where CodEmpleado = @CodEmpleado";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, ObjConexion);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ruta", Obj.Ruta);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", Obj.Foto);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodEmpleado", Obj.Iduser_Empleado);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                ObjConexion.Open();
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    resultado = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Mensaje = "No se pudo Actualizar la Imagen";
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultado = false;
            Mensaje = ex.Message;
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Agradezco de ante mano si me pueden ayudar en esto ya que es importante para el proyecto que se pueda realizar esta función.

Comment: Por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta añadiendo el código como texto de un [ejemplo _mínimo_ verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).